# Having a hard time working with floats

Tags: objective-c

*I wasn't really sure what to name the title.*

I'm checking to see if the value of two floats are the same. If I use `printf()` or `NSLog()`, the values return 0.750000. However, a line like `if (value1 == value2) { return TRUE; }` doesn't work. I can assume that in reality, the floats are beyond the 7 decimal places, and `printf()` / `NSLog()` can't return a value beyond 7 decimals.

I tried googling a way to see how I could cut down a float to a smaller amount of decimal places, or simply convert it to another data type, but I didn't get such luck so far.

Comment: sigh... http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decide of an epsilon that is the maximum value under which number are equals. Like

```
  #define EPSILON 0.0001

  if (fabs(floatA - floatB) < EPSILON) { retun TRUE; }
```

`fabs(x)` returns the absolute value of the `double` *x*.

You may also want to use the `double` instead of `float` data type (`double` is twice the size of a `float`).

Answer (score 4):

You might want to peek at `float.h` (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Floating-Point-Parameters.html) for a non-arbitrary definition of epsilon. In particular, `FLT_EPSILON` and `FLT_DIG`.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you compare floating point numbers you need to use a tolerance:

```
if (Abs(value1 - value2) < epsilon)
{
}
```

where epsilon is a value such as 0.000001